# Adding and removing WFS layer using Leaflet control?

Tags: leaflet, wfs

I need add and quit a layer WFS vía Leaflet Control, So far I can add the WFS layer to the map, but how do I add it and remove it using the leaflet control?

This is my code.

```
var owsrootUrl ='http://geo.gporellana.gob.ec/geoinfo/gadpo/wfs';

var defaultParameters = {

          service: 'WFS',
          version: '2.0.0',
          request: 'GetFeature',
    typeName: 'gadpo:clima_estacion',
    outputFormat: 'application/json',
    format_options:'callback:getJson',
    SrsName:'EPSG:4326'
};

var parametres = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);

var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parametres);
var WFSLayer =null;

var ajax = $.ajax({

    url:URL,
    dataType:'json',
    jsonpCallback:'getJson',
    success: function(response){
       WFSLayer = L.geoJson(response,{
            style:function(feature){
                return {
                    stroke:true,
                    fillColor:'FFFFFF',
                    fillOpacity:0
                };
            },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
                popupOptions = {maxWidth: 200};
                layer.bindPopup("<span style='color: green'>Estación Meteorológica</span> " + feature.properties.nam, popupOptions);
            }
        });//.addTo(mapa);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [the relevant Leaflet tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/#layers-control). In your case this would look similar to this:

```
 L.control.layers({}, {"Climate stations": WFSLayer).addTo(map);
```

You will receive a layer control with a checkbox that lets you toggle your `WFSLayer` on and off.